# QAF Dashboard.html is empty

Tags: rest, testng, bdd, qaf

I have downloaded the QAF Maven project and imported into Eclipse. I have created BDD test case for one of the RESTFull service and I am able to run it as TestNG Test. I see the result folder created with the date and timestamp created under test-results folder. When I try to refresh the Dashboard.html I don't see any results and it’s empty.

Please let me know if I have to update my POM or any other property file.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening dashboard.htm in firefox. 
You need to open local dashboard.htm in Firfox (prefered), Edge or Safari. If you are opening in chrome you need to set allow file access from file. If dashboard.htm served through http server, for example jenkins then you can open in any browser.